# Annoying Bug in banner cycle

Tags: jquery, cycle, banner

I have created a rotating banner script for a new site I'm developing [View banner here(it rotates every 10 seconds)](http://www.atlas-display.co.uk/index.php)

Unfortunately to the transition seems to be a biut buggy, and the image will fade out, show the same image again and then fade in the new one. I think I have made a simple error somewhere, but can't figure out where it is. the code used to cycle the banners is:

In document ready:

```
if ($('.home').length > 0){
        $('<img width="100%" />').attr('src', '/assets/img/backgrounds/home/hero'+homecount+'.jpg').load(function(){
                $('.hero').append( $(this) );
                $('.hero img').fadeIn('medium').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow', loopImages);
                setHeroHeight();
        });
    }
```

Outside document ready:

```
function loopImages(){
    homecount = homecount+1;
    if (homecount > 5){
        homecount = 1;  
    }
    $('.hero img')
        .attr('src', '/assets/img/backgrounds/home/hero'+homecount+'.jpg')
        .load(function(){ $('.hero img').fadeIn('fast')}).delay(10000).fadeOut('slow', loopImages);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I visited your page in Chrome and did not see the issue you were describing. However, it is taking a LONG time for those images to load. Have you considered preloading the images? Check [here](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript) for a jQuery image preload plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar problem when i was trying to show a series of quotes in a div, i achieved it by using the folowing code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   function runIt(){
     $('*img*').each(function(i, elem) {
       $("*container*").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
         $(this).html($(elem).html());
       }).fadeIn(1000, runIt);
     });
   };
   runIt()
 });
```

`*img*`: here you're calling your images

`*container*`: this is the element where you want your image to appear.

You can see the code in action here: [dinwoodie.net](http://www.dinwoodie.net/index.php?id=5)

Comment: As mentioned by @jwatts1980, for this answer you'll need to preload your images, into a holding div eg: `<div id="holdimgs"><img /><img />` then use `$('#holdimgs img')each(function(i, elem){...});` Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the acript alex. I had to make a minor tweak as you can't select the html of an image. Wrapped them all in <p> tags and it works sweet as a nut now. Many thanks. David